# Crystal Reports- how to suppress page header if details section is empty?

Tags: crystal-reports

I tried onLastRecord, onFirstRecord and NextIsNull functions but they does not work. When there isn't any row on last page onLastRecord works and page header doesn't show up. But if there is one row on last page, page header still disappears but I want to display it. How can I fix it? Please help me:)

[This is my report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Bju.png)

[When there isn't any row on last page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXfCC.png)

[When there is one row on last page, header still disappears(but I want to display:))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSuUB.png)

[This my formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y91QV.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crystal Reports - Suppress a Page Header if the page has 0 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294027/crystal-reports-suppress-a-page-header-if-the-page-has-0-records)